# TCL Entry box read to variable

Tags: tcl

I have a single entry box called 'entrySerial' where it will have the user input the serial of the device.  This serial should be placed into a variable so it can then be sent into a different procedure.  How do I take what the user has entered and place it into the variable?  This will occur only after the user presses a button -- I don't want the input being read as the user types it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [entry widget](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm) has a [-textvariable](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/options.htm#M-textvariable) option which takes the name of a global variable which will hold the text value of the widget. This is live so it always holds the current value as the user types however you can use the [-validatecommand](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M-validatecommand) option to run a command on certain conditions as described for the [-validate](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/entry.htm#M-validate) option. One of these is a key press event (where you could check for Enter) and another useful one is to do the validation on loss of focus. eg:

```
set value "test"
entry .e -textvariable ::value -validate focusout -validatecommand {puts $::value; return 1}
pack .e -side left
pack [button .b -text Ok] -side right
```

That should print the entry value when you loose focus either by clicking another control or application or by using Tab to switch to another control.